# populate multiple gridview from one database

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a table which contains information of registered employees, so number of rows in this table keep changing. In my web application, I want to show employees information on single page. I want to show employees info in three different grid view (horizontally- where each grid view will contain 1/3 of total rows in table). How can i do that?

Comment: I think we could bind the grid view to a query that you write for...  [Showing grid from SQL](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14249/How-to-populate-DataGridView-GridView-with-SQL-sta)

Comment: you can use paging rather than showing it into the three grid-view. Or if you data is in data-set then you can easily divide it into three data tables and then bind your each gridvew from the corresponding data-table.

Comment: So if there are 10 rows in datatable, then 1-3 comes in 1st, 4-6 in 2nd and 7-10 in 3rd grid right?